# How do I interactively reduce (or stop) the sliding speed of a jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I want to slow down and eventually stop my slide-show when the mouse pointer hovers over it.

Here is the script I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#slideshow').cycle({    
        fx:     'fade',    
        speed:  'fast',    
        timeout: 1000,    
        pager:  '#slider_nav',    
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {    
            // return sel string for existing anchor    
            return '#slider_nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
        }
    });
});
```

This is the website I am working on: http://www.getushopping.com/.  If you visit the site, I am talking about the slide-show playing closest to the top of the page.

Comment: -1 for zero effort.  Maybe I don't understand the question... you're asking _"how to reduce the speed"_ while the `speed:` parameter (set to `'fast'`) is right there in the code you provided, plain as day.  Did you already try changing it to `'slow'`?  As far as the second part of the question, did you at least read the documentation for the plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're using the jQuery Cycle Plugin, so i'd check the "Beginner Demos" here:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html

From the page above:

> *The speed option defines the number of milliseconds it will take to transition from one slide to the next.*

To Pause when the mouse gets over it, read #4 on that page.

Looks like you need to include this option:

```
pause:  1
```

So your code will end up looking something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#slideshow').cycle({

        fx:     'fade',

        speed:  '1000', // This is 1000 mili-seconds, or 1 second

        pause:  1,            

        timeout: 1000,

        pager:  '#slider_nav',

        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {

            // return sel string for existing anchor

            return '#slider_nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

USe these settings to slow and pause slider on hover.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#slideshow').cycle({

        fx:     'fade', 
        speed:   300, 
        timeout: 3000, 
        pause:   1

    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
speed: 1000,  //or some other value your prefer like 300, 400, etc
...
```